# Is there a way to test for elements in a collection without a specific order?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Here's how I test elements of a collection right now:

```java
.then()
    .spec(userSpec("users[0]", first))
    .spec(userSpec("users[1]", second))
```

The problem here is that the test is tied to a particular order of elements.

I'm looking for a way to test elements in a collection without being tied to their order and can't find any. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to look into GPath (The groovy expression language). Using GPath you can identify a specific user. For example let's say that your JSON document returned by the server looks like this:

```
{  
   "users":[  
      {  
         "id":0,
         "name":"Jane"
      },
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"John"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can then use GPath in to verify that the user with id equal to 0 has name "Jane" and the user with id equal to 1 is called "John":

```
then().
       body("users.find { it.id == 0 }.name", equalTo("Jane")).
       body("users.find { it.id == 1 }.name", equalTo("John")). ..
```

This can be made more reusable by using a root path:

```
then().
       rootPath("users.find { it.id == %d }.name").
       body(withArgs(0), equalTo("Jane")).
       body(withArgs(1), equalTo("John")). ..
```